# SQL Server Mgmt Studio 2012 - Automatic Delimiter Highlighting

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms-2012

Recently upgraded from SSMS 2005 to 2012. I noticed that, when writing a query, the parentheses were no longer bold when closing them.

I checked around the web and found the references to Automatic Delimiter Highlighting, but that box is already checked under Tools | Options.

Any ideas what I might be missing, or where else I can look for a setting to change?

Thanks!

Comment: SSMS 2012 has options to configure font styles, maybe the font style for highlighted text is exactly the same as non highlighted text

Comment: Thanks, I checked that as well. It is set to bold the highlighted delimiters, but does not do so.

Comment: did you ever fix this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: I think I needed to enable IntelliSense, if I remember right? Tools, Options, Text Editor, Transact-SQL, IntelliSense, check Enable IntelliSense.